# Converting metres per second to minutes per kilometre

Tags: javascript, math, strava

I have a value given in metres per second (mps) retrieved from the Strava API and I want to convert this minutes per kilometre (pace). On the surface this seems simple, off the top of my head I came up with the following:

```js
const metresPerSecond = 3.358;
var metresPerMinute = metresPerSecond*60;
var minutesPerKm = 1000/metresPerMinute;

console.log(minutesPerKm); // 4.96
```

I've also tried doing it by using the time & distance values like so:

```js
const timeInSeconds = 1203;
const distanceInMetres = 4040;
var pace = (timeInSeconds/distanceInMetres)/60*1000;

console.log(pace); // 4.96
```

Initially I assumed this was correct but on looking at the pace value in Strava for this activity the value is `4.58`. I thought this could be because they are doing something clever with their data such as removing stationary sections etc, but I input the time/distance values into this [site here](https://www.active.com/fitness/calculators/pace) and it gave me the same `4.58` value so there is clearly another way of doing this that I'm not understanding.

Anybody any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Assuming they've not each made the same mistake would be my tongue in cheek answer. Think about it... 12kmh is exactly 5 mins per km. 12kmh is a 3 and a third meters a second. If we plug 3.333 into your formula, we are returned the answer of 5.000500050005 - ergo, you're right and they're not. :shrugs:

Comment: Even I tried but still the answer was 4.9, are you sure they are correct?

Comment: 4.96 minutes IS 4:58, because 0.96 * 60 seconds = 57.6 seconds

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're doing it entirely correct. The only thing you're missing is that you should convert the 'leftover' minutes from decimal minutes to seconds.

> const timeInSeconds = 1203;
>   const distanceInMetres = 4040;
>   var pace = (timeInSeconds/distanceInMetres)/60*1000;
>   var leftover = pace % 1;
>   var minutes = pace - leftover;
>   var seconds = Math.round(leftover * 60);
>   console.log(minutes+":"+seconds)

Results in 4:58

Comment: Ohhhhh of course haha! Thanks so much, what a dumb mistake on my part.